# Can't encrypt external hard drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt an external drive of mine using Apple's built in drive encryption tool into OS X through Finder.

The drive is formatted as Mac OS Extended(Journaled) and I'm plugging the drive through USB 2.0. Also I'm running Mavericks with all the latest updates.

Even though after a restart or switching to another Mac, I'm getting the following error:

> Unable to create a new Core Storage logical volume group.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you plug-in your external hard drive? How do you try and encrypt the drive?

Comment: Sorry about my sluggish explanation. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Sorry I can't help you then, I don't know where is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

OK, I'm running El Capitan OS X 10.11. The Apple app "Disk Utility" is useless to create encryption, as it typically returns

> Operation Failed with status 28

So the fix is to use a little **terminal** magic.  After adding your USB drive to the Mac, run terminal
At the command-line prompt, enter:

```
diskutil list
```

You will see your main (internal) disk listed, as well as your USB:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            499.4 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.1 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +499.1 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 B0B7A5AA-7D8D-41E3-8565-82E4E1D685D5
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *31.5 GB    disk2
   1:             Windows_FAT_32 KINGSTON                31.5 GB    disk2s1
```

You can spot your external drive by its size -- mine is 32 GB, which, after overhead is around 31.5.  In other words, its name is KINGSTON at drive identifier **disk2s1**.
Now, using your USB drive's device identifier in place of **disk2s1**, pick a suitable name for your new drive.  I like **thing2**:

```
diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ thing2 /dev/disk2
```

About 30 seconds of progress later, you should get:

```
Finished erase on disk2
```

Now, open a Finder window, and right click your newly named disk.  Pick the option **encrypt** .  In my case, the USB 3.0 encryption took about 12 minutes of effort for 32 GB (45MB/s write).  You will know you are done, when the drive activity light goes out.

Comment: I can't try it out at the moment but will give it a try when I have the chance. Thanks.