# why is there a significant chunk of disk space (~124Gb) that Disk Utility isn't able to access?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, ssd

~124GB is missing/inaccessible from Disk Utility..   I'm unable to resize the main partition, I'm unable to manipulate the missing space (delete, etc without erasing the entire disk).   First aid on the disk and the partition said there's a problem and to boot to recovery and run First Aid there.   Did that and it reports it cannot fix the problem.

The disk is encrypted, I don't know if that matters.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2: FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF Macintosh HD            375.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +374.8 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 0E3E3C70-5FE7-484E-826B-828CDA8F3471
                                 Unlocked Encrypted

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +686.4 MB   disk2
```

[image][image]

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @Allan - yeah - why is there a significant chunk of disk space that diskutility isn't seeing?

Comment: Do you know how your partition map became corrupted? I would expect disk0s2 to be of type Apple_CoreStorage and be 1 GB or so less in size than disk0 which I believe matches your space expectations. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/214827/5472 for what I expect a healthy 500 GB drive to look like with 499.4 and 499.1 sizings on the physical and virtual Macintosh HD core storage volumes respectively.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the GUID partition table/map for that drive was corrupted, and that is why 124GB were missing.

The solution is:

1. boot to recovery mode
2. Launch terminal
3. run `gpt show` to see partition indexes, start blocks and sizes,
   note carefully.
4. use `gpt remove -i <index>` to remove each partition in reverse order
5. use `gpt add -b <start block> -i <index> -s <size> -t <type UUID>` to rebuild the partition map in reverse order.

Note:  the UUID `53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC` is for partition type Apple_CoreStorage, which is what the encrypted partitions use.   EFI boot and also recovery partitions are `426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC`

[related question.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/239759/partition-type-suddenly-ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffff-drive-unmountable)